# Must have tool set for MOSS 2007 development

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm trying to compile a list of Must have tools/extensions for developing MOSS 2007 to build a dev machine. The dev os is Window 2008 R2 64 bit.

1. MOSS 2007
2. Visual Studio 2008
3. Sharepoint Designer
4. WSS/Office Server SDK
5. Visual Studio 2008 Extensions for WSS 3.0

Is there any additional required/nice to have tools?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SharePointDevWiki.com covers this well:

Basic tools:
[Building a SharePoint Development environment](http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com/display/public/Building+a+SharePoint+Development+Environment)

Then take your pick from this exhaustive list:
[SharePoint Development tools](http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com/display/public/SharePoint+Development+Tools)

My must-have items in my toolbox (some already mentioned) are:

- VMWare Player
- SharePoint Manager 2007
- Powershell
- SPWakeUp
- NotePad++
- SharePoint Inspector
- SharePoint Feature Manager
- SPDisposeCheck
- Application Pool Manager
- Beyond Compare 2
- STSADM Win
- ULS Viewer
- Imtech Fields Explorer
- Imtech List Generator
- Firefox and Firebug
- Stramit CamlViewer 2007
- CAML Intellisense
- U2U CAML Query Builder
- Fiddler
- Gary Lapointe's Custom STSADM Extensions
- Scott Hillier Features on Codeplex
- SharePoint Sushi

Comment: Great list! In fact I might just download some of those now!

Comment: Of this list, the two absolute must haves in my mind are SPDisposeCheck and U2U CAML Query Builder. Do not deploy a custom DLL to production without first running SPDisposeCheck.

Answer (score 3):

[.Net Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/index.htm)

[Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

CSS debugging tools like IE developer toolbar, FireBug etc

Comment: Reflector and FireBug make up for SharePoint's sparse documentation.

Answer (score 2):

[SharePoint Manager](http://www.codeplex.com/spm) is updated for 2010, but the 2007 release is still available.  It's a great tool for browsing the innards of a SharePoint site hierarchy.

[SPM http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=spm&DownloadId=23663](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=spm&DownloadId=23663)

Comment: This is probably the most important tool to have for SharePoint developer (well, except VS and WSPBuilder or STSDEV or VSeWSS)

Answer (score 1):

On MOSS 2007 several people I respect use [WSPBuilder](http://www.codeplex.com/wspbuilder) and swear by it.  For hard-core dev work you may find [DbgView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) invaluable.  Finally, a solid diff/merge tool like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) often comes in handy.  Of course, your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

I think [STSDEV](http://stsdev.codeplex.com/) was a great tool and grants more fine-grained control over the WSP creation process than the Visual Studio Extensions.  I admit that I gave up on the VSeWSS tools early on, so they might be awesome now, but using STSDEV has been a breeze to integrate into the build process.  Also, since the source is available, it's easy to fix or extend on a whim!

Comment: The VSeWSS CTP 1.3 was a lot better than the previous versions, but still not good enough to make me use them. I haven't checked out STSDEV but there's nothing like the fine-grained control you get from manually doing your manifest.xml and .dff files ;-)

Comment: I'll pile on with the STSDEV love. I prefer STSDEV's flexibility over either VSeWSS or WSPBuilder. Although, Visual Studio 2010 will probably replace them all. I haven't tried a 2007 project in VS 2010 yet, but I'm liking what I see for 2010 projects.

Comment: I had to do some work with VSeWSS recently. It has improved significantly - from impossible to use to merely painful.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say IronPython is an invaluable tool for experiments with the SharePoint object model and short scripting tasks - of course, unless you already use Powershell.

How to begin - http://blog.glenc.net/2007/08/12/sharepoint-meet-python/

Answer (score 0):

Here is another good list for [SharePoint 2007 developer tools](http://extdev.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/sharepoint-2007-must-have-developer-tools/)